# Calculating Rate of Change

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data set called "yield":

```
yield <- data.frame(fruits = c("apples", "apples", "apples", "oranges", "oranges", 
         "oranges", "pears", "pears", "pears"), year = rep(2008:2010, 3), 
         count = c(10, 13, 7, 5, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20))
```

[image: data]

I want to determine which fruit has the largest rate of change between 2008 and 2010. The closest I have gotten to was:

`diff(yield$count)/yield[-nrow(yield),] * 100`

but not only does it affect my `fruits` and `year` columns, the results are incorrect.

Comment: Please post data as plain text, not images, so users can copy/paste it easily.

Comment: What is the formula for rate of change?

Comment: (count for current year - count for previous year)/ count for previous year * 100

Comment: Your formulae is correct _if and only if_ you also group by fruit.

Comment: Thanks, I have thought about using the dplyr function group_by but not sure how to make it work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your formula, I think this `dplyr` solution works. You need to group by fruit and then order by year, for `lag` to work correctly:

```
library(dplyr)
yield %>% 
  group_by(fruits) %>% 
  arrange(fruits, year) %>% 
  mutate(rate = 100 * (count - lag(count))/lag(count)) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  fruits   year count   rate
  <fct>   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 apples   2008 10.0    NA  
2 apples   2009 13.0    30.0
3 apples   2010  7.00 - 46.2
4 oranges  2008  5.00   NA  
5 oranges  2009 12.0   140  
6 oranges  2010 14.0    16.7
7 pears    2008 16.0    NA  
8 pears    2009 18.0    12.5
9 pears    2010 20.0    11.1
```

Comment: That worked out perfectly thank you very much. Just a few quick questions, group_by lets R know to conduct the analysis (the mutate function) purely based on the fruits variables and the lag function tells R to start at the 2nd row of each unique variable?

Comment: `group_by` ensures that any operation is on a "per fruit" basis. `lag` just means "the row previous to the current row". So `count - lag(count)` means "for each row of column `count`, calculate value - previous row value". The first entry per group is `NA` because the first row has no previous row.

Comment: I should clarify that while the default for `lag` is 1 row previous, you can also specify 2, 3...n rows previous.

Comment: in case this confuses anyone searching for a similar solution: while lag is in base (stats), it's the dplyr version used here which is required here.

Comment: What about if one needs to calculate growth rate to a baseline year - let say a fixed year?? which in Excel is $A$ to keep a fixed observation. What would be the script in R?

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is the same as a `data.table` one-liner.

#### First, the data

```
R> library(data.table)
R> df <- data.frame(fruits=rep(c("apples", "oranges", "pears"), each=3), 
+                   year=rep(2008:2010, 3), 
+                   count=c(10,13,7,5,12,14,16,18,20))
R> dt <- as.data.table(df)
R> dt
    fruits year count
1:  apples 2008    10
2:  apples 2009    13
3:  apples 2010     7
4: oranges 2008     5
5: oranges 2009    12
6: oranges 2010    14
7:   pears 2008    16
8:   pears 2009    18
9:   pears 2010    20
R>
```

#### Second, one line

```
R> dt[ , .(year, change=100*(count-shift(count,1))/shift(count,1)), by=fruits]
    fruits year   change
1:  apples 2008       NA
2:  apples 2009  30.0000
3:  apples 2010 -46.1538
4: oranges 2008       NA
5: oranges 2009 140.0000
6: oranges 2010  16.6667
7:   pears 2008       NA
8:   pears 2009  12.5000
9:   pears 2010  11.1111
R>
```

We group `by=fruits` and in each block show `year` and the desired rate of change as `100*(current-prev)/prev` where we use `shift()` to lag the 
`count` series.

Comment: Thank you, so I would have to convert the data frame to a data table first?

Comment: See line 3 in my first segment: `dt <- as.data.table(df)`.  `setDT()` is an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Base R one liner:

```
yield$roc <- with(yield, ave(count, fruits, FUN = function(x){c(0, c(diff(x), 0)/x)[seq_along(x)]}))
```

Base R if you want NA's in place of 0s and the actual percentage rate (i.e. *100):

```
yield$roc <- with(yield, ave(count, fruits, 
              FUN = function(x){c(NA_real_, c(diff(x), 0)/x)[seq_along(x)] * 100}))
```

Base R function:

```
roc <- function(ordered_num_vec){
  c(0, c(diff(ordered_num_vec), 0) / ordered_num_vec)[seq_along(ordered_num_vec)]
}

with(yield, ave(count, fruits, FUN = roc))
```